# Deploy Angular 2 website to EcoWebhosting

Tags: angular, web-hosting

I made a one page website with Angular 2 (localhost) and I'm trying to deploy it on EcoWebHosting. I uploaded the entire site with Filezilla but it didn't work. How can I do it? I found a similar question here on stackoverflow but the links provided for the solution are broken. I read that I have to import a few javascript files in my index.html file but I don't know what to do exactly. I need a solution step by step because I'm a newbie with Angular.

Thank you.

Dorina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Build your application with the CLI.

In your console, run

```
ng build --prod
```

At the root of your project.

2. A `dist` folder has been generated. This is your SPA (Single Page Application).
3. Take the content of that `dist` folder, and sent it with your FTP to your website.

You have nothing else to do. Everything has been done for you by the CLI.

Comment: Well, not really, I didn't develop the CLI, I'm just using it. But no problem !